# how to capitalize the grid headings in web2py

Tags: grid, web2py, capitalize

I want the headings of my GRID should be in capital letters.
If I am using

```
headers='fieldname:capitalize',
```

as one of the argument in grid its not working.
Please need expert opinion.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `'fieldname:capitalize'` notation works only with `SQLTABLE`, not `SQLFORM.grid`. Also, that simply capitalizes the first letter of the field name, not all the letters. If you want all caps headers in the grid, you could do something like:

```
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.mytable,
                    headers={str(f):f.name.upper() for f in db.mytable})
```

Note, if you don't provide a `headers` argument, the grid simply uses the `.label` attribute of each field in the header, so you can also define the `.label` attributes in all caps. To do that automatically, you could do:

```
for field in db.mytable:
    field.label = field.name.upper()
```